# Heroku installing error eclipse plug in

Tags: heroku

while installing heroku I got this error msg...

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Heroku Eclipse Plugin 1.0.0 (com.heroku.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0) Missing requirement: Heroku Eclipse Plugin 1.0.0 (com.heroku.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100' but it could not be found

I have eclipse Standard
Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following.

```
 Eclipse v 3.7 or higher is required. 
 Disable the antivirus during installation.
```